# navigationItem button not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I have a `UINavigationItem` i am trying to show a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Now the problem is i added them correctly, they're functional and working 100%.

but they're not showing on the  `UINavigationBar`.

Now for the flow I am doing the following.

1- I am hiding the back button, like this

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(isBackHidden, animated: false)
```

2- I am adding those 2 buttons using a function dynamically at run time, when a user tap on a `UIButton`.

```
let rightBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button.Done".localized, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.saveButtonTapped))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem     
let leftBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button.Cancel".localized, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelButtonTapped))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .red // still nothing    
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarItem
```

3- I have tried to use those functions and still the same result

```
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem?, animated: Bool)
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(UIBarButtonItem?, animated: Bool)
```

**Summary** :

I have tried to change the `tintColor` as they're functionally working i thought it was a color problem.

I have tried to use them inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` thinking it might be a thread problem since it dynamic.

I have  debugged and check for the items in the `UINavigationItem` and they're exist.

**What is going on mainly:**

The buttons are not shown but they are working just fine when tapped on their places on the `UINavigationItem`.

Comment: So, you are trying to add a "left" bar button item at run time based on a specific event, correct?

Comment: Yes, left and right, @AhmadF

Comment: I tried your second code snippet and it works fine for me... Do you think is there any extra information could be useful to mention?

Comment: I have a textfield in a cell that becomes a first responder before setting the buttons

Comment: @AhmadF they work when tapping on  navItem but they are not showing ..

Comment: is this code title: "Button.Cancel".localized set title ... what does localized do"

Comment: return a localized value, and it works fine i debugged it and tried a plain string same result

Comment: Is there any customization for the navigation bar/item in the previous view controller(s)?

Comment: @AhmadF good point, but no, it was hidden then shown in this view controller inside the didLoad, if its hidden the back button would not even appear i mean i would notice but no other customs

Comment: For the purpose of checking what's the issue, try to add bar button with a custom view: `let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Button.Done", for: .normal)
        button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        navigationItem.setRightBarButton(buttonItem, animated: false)`

Comment: .... bde amoslk, it works.. can you please post it and explain why and what is the problem

Comment: @7bebMrto btw, are you pretty sure that `"Button.Done".localized` and `"Button.Cancel".localized` return a non `nil` or empty string?

Comment: i used .localized with your snippet it works i am using them all around the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186464/discussion-between-ahmad-f-and-7bebmrto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now the problem is i added them correctly, they're functional and
>   working 100%.
>
> but they're not showing on the  UINavigationBar.

Based on what you mentioned, it is just a UI issue -for unknown reason-.

So what you could do to confirm that there are button items will be shown in the navigation item is to let the bar button item to has a *custom* view. Adding a `UIButton` as a custom view for `UIBarButtonItem` would be valid, like this:

```
// right
let rightButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
rightButton.setTitle("Button.Done".localized, for: .normal)
rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)
navigationItem.setRightBarButton(rightBarButtonItem, animated: true)

// left
let leftButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
leftButton.setTitle("Button.Cancel".localized, for: .normal)
leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftButton)
navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```

Therefore, for any needed UI update, you could edit `rightButton` and `leftButton`, example:

```
leftButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
leftButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
leftButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

In addition, I would assume that there is no need to call:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(isBackHidden, animated: false)
```

When setting the left bar button item, it should be a replacement for the back button by default.