# cannot create UIBarButtonItem on viewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a UIBarButtonItem by doing this function:

```
func setupBackButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 40)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
```

it works on other screens that i add it, 
but on a spefic view controller it just doens't add anything.

Here is the storyboard of other screens that it works on them :

[image]

[image]

And here is the sotryboard in the screen that Doesn't work:

[image]

[image]

what might be the problem , and why i might not see the button ?

Comment: Is it a UI issue? I mean if you tried to tap it will its selector get called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [navigationItem button not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126284/navigationitem-button-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

swift 4:

I added a navigation controller: 
[image]

create UIBarButtonItem on viewcontroller :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(myLeftBarButtonItem(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
}


@objc func myLeftBarButtonItem(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!) {
    print("myLeftBarButtonItem")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try this: 
if you add image in left navbar then write this :

```
let leftAddBarButtonItemMenu = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.btnLeftMenuClicked(sender:)))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [leftAddBarButtonItemMenu]
```

if you add image in right navbar then write this :

```
let rightNavBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.btnRightClicked(sender:)))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [rightNavBarItem]
```

If add Title in right navbar then write this:

```
let rightNavBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.btnRightClicked(sender:)))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [rightNavBarItem]
```

It may Helps you. Thank you